# Esp32 Low Frequency PWM

Tags: esp32

Good morning I need to perform a 0.4 Hz pwm and with LEDC I can only reach 1 hz in esp32. Could you tell me if there is a possibility to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are currently using the functions from some esp32 library. Like in the Arduino world, there is another way. You can set the right Bits so you manually create a PWM signal. Here is the Technical Reference Manual:
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf
You will find all the relevant Information in chapter 14 (LED_PWM).